# Django-openid-auth multiple account login

Tags: django, openid

I just started playing around with openid auth and I wonder if someone can tell me how to configure the settings so that it displays multiple social media providers at the login page instead of setting a single sign in at the settings.py. The setting I am using is just a Google redirect account login page.

OPENID_SSO_SERVER_URL = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id'

I would like to have more than 1 option for the users to choose the account sign in (e.g. Facebook, yahoo, etc.).

Many Thanks!

Comment: have a look at http://github.com/omab/django-social-auth you can use its pipeline system for customizations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just not Settings you have to provide corresponding views and Templates

Ref:
 https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/blob/master/example/app/views.py